# CS50 Android Pokedex: Why does my 'Catch Pokemon' button work only once?

Tags: android, cs50

Here is the relevant code in  `activity_pokemon.xml`:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/catching_button"
    android:text="STATE 1"
    android:onClick="toggleCatch"/>
```

Here is the relevant code in `PokemonActivity.java`:

```
public class PokemonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...    
    private Button buttonView;

    @Override    
    protected void OnCreate(...) {
        ...
        buttonView = findViewById(R.id.catching_button);
        ...
    }

    ...

    // Implements catching functionality.
    public boolean pokemonIsCaught = false;

    public void toggleCatch(View view) {

        // Catch the Pokemon if it is not caught.
        if (!pokemonIsCaught) {
            pokemonIsCaught = true;
            buttonView.setText("Release");
        }

        // Release the Pokemon if it is caught.
        if (pokemonIsCaught) {
            pokemonIsCaught = false;
            buttonView.setText("Catch");
        }
    }
```

**Expected Behaviour**

1. The initial text of the button is `STATE 1` (a placeholder for `Catch`). (This works.)
2. Pressing the button changes its text to `Release`. (Instead, the text is changed to `Catch`. This puzzles me -- `pokemonIsCaught` was initially `False`!)
3. Any subsequent presses of the button toggles its text between `Release` and `Catch`. (Instead, the text stays at `Catch`.)

Comment: can you share the code for the listener for `buttonView`?

Comment: @Stachu Is a listener necessary? My [instructions (see heading 'Catching')](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/tracks/mobile/android/pokedex/) did not mention any listener. I thought that `android:onClick="toggleCatch"` in `activity.pokemon.xml` would call `toggleCatch()`.

Comment: ah, I see it now. To be honest I've never used it like that, so I'm not sure. Can you add `Log.d("PokemonActivity ", "toggleCatch" + String.valueOf(pokemonIsCaught))` in toggleCatch to see if it changes pokemonIsCaught  when you click it?

Comment: @Stachu Done. The log reports that `pokemonIsCaught` is false after all button presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you click for the first time the click changes `pokemonIsCaught` to true and  then changes it back again (because the second if statement is now true). So basically your methond changes `pokemonIsCaught`  like this
false ->(click) true (first if) false (second if)
this should work as you expect

```
 public void toggleCatch(View view) {

        // Catch the Pokemon if it is not caught.
        if (!pokemonIsCaught) {
            pokemonIsCaught = true;
            buttonView.setText("Release");
        } else { // Release the Pokemon if it is caught.
            pokemonIsCaught = false;
            buttonView.setText("Catch");
        }
    }
```

Comment: _sigh_ This solved my issue. I should probably avoid writing or thinking about `if` statements like `switch` statements in the future. Thanks!